# How can I fix the broken keyboard shortcut in VS2012 to copy from schema-compare definition text?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts, sql-server-data-tools

If I run an SQL Schema Compare in Visual Studio 2012 (part of the SQL Server Data Tools add-on), I can highlight text inside an object definition, and can right-click to select "Copy (Ctrl+C)", and it works.  But actually pressing Ctrl+C doesn't work — absolutely nothing happens.

How can I fix this?

What I've tried:  messing around in the Keyboard Shortcuts dialog, which doesn't seem to list that specific version of the copy command.

Other info:  the default Edit.Copy command doesn't seem to be enabled; the Edit menu's Copy command is greyed out when selecting in the Object Definition panel, curiously.

Comment: It's a bug in the current release, with no workaround right now. It's been fixed internally and will be included in the next SQL Server tooling update - for more information see Connect bug http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/944911/object-definitions-pane-of-a-schema-compare-select-all-and-copy-omissions.

Comment: @KevinCunnane  Dang.  That seems to be the answer.  If you repost this as one, I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This a bug in the July 2014 release, with no workaround right now. It's been fixed internally and will be included in the next SQL Server tooling update - for more information see this [Connect bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/944911/object-definitions-pane-of-a-schema-compare-select-all-and-copy-omissions).